# mysql foreign key not violated

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, myisam, referential-integrity

I am using `mysql`.

When I add a **foreign key** to a table it is done without any errors.

When the table structure is described i see MUL under the key field like I see the the PRI for the columns set as the primary key.

But when I try to violate the foreign key constraint by adding a value absent in the parent table in the child table it is correctly inserted without any errors.With my little knowledge in `SQL` this is against the rules of the foreign key.

Any Ideas why this is happening or how I can fix it?

Comment: Please show us the table definitions, the foreign key, and the data you try to insert.

Comment: There are several situations where MySQL will simply ignore your foreign key definition without telling you.

Comment: What ENGINE are you using on your table (MyISAM, InnoDB, ...)?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you use the default myisam engine. It doesnt support foreign keys...

In this case put "engine=innodb" at the end of he create tables.

Comment: lighten up - The question is "Any Ideas why this is happening or how I can fix it?"  Lajos answered it.  In fact he answered both of them.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder, this is the correct answer.  Mysql surprises many people when it doesn't enforce FKs, and the fix is to use innodb instead of the default engine.

Comment: +1 and for what it's worth, InnoDB *is* the default engine since MySQL 5.5, which was released in 2010.

Comment: @BillKarwin: even with InnoDB you can define foreign keys that are silently ignored